# Subframe creating a new task on the taskbar

Tags: java, windows, swing

I am trying to make an MP3 player, something similar to WinAmp. I'm currently having a minor issue with the GUI:

I have a main frame that will have the equalizer/volume/time elapsed etc. on it, and a sub-frame that will be the playlist. The sub-frame is a class that extends `JFrame` and is a field inside the main frame's class. Currently I have a button on the mainframe that changes the visibility of the sub-frame. My problem is: when the sub-frame appears, it creates a new task on the task-bar (when it's invisible the task disappears as well). I know it's not a major issue, but I find it somewhat annoying. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Although I've paid money to register WinAmp, I find it's tendency to have more than one free-floating GUI element, to be quite irritating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The subframe is a class that extends JFrame*

take `JDialog` instead of `JFrame`. This will not create a new task item on task bar.

Comment: or JWindow, but this is Un-Decorated by defalut, one for nearest to the 10K +1

Comment: Can I add Components to JDialog aswell then? Need to add atleast a JTextArea.

Comment: Yes you can add components in JDialog all most all of them are supported in JDialog.

Comment: @István Kohn that same as you adds JComponents to the JFrame, I don't know any differencies ...